# efficient way to check if an array has all integers between 0 and n-1

Tags: c, arrays, complexity-theory

in regarding to my previous post: [Complexity to find if there is a missing element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59869005/complexity-to-find-if-there-is-a-missing-element-in-an-array) --> i am trying to solve an algorithm to check if an array has all elements between 0 and n - 1 in the most efficient way (time complexity wise) without an extra array,. i came up with two solutions. could you help me determine which one is more efficient? which one should i turn in? thank you.

```
/* first attempt */

int check_missing_a(int *a, int n)
{
    int i, flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n) //check for unwanted integers
            return 0;

        while (i != a[i])
        {
            swap(&a[a[i]], &a[i]); //puts numbers in their index

            flag++;
            if (flag > 1 && a[i] == a[a[i]]) //check for duplicates
                return 0;
        }
        flag = 0;
    }

    return 1;
}


/* second attempt */

int check_missing_b(int *a, int n)
{
    int i, sum_a = 0, sum_i = 0, sum_aa = 0, sum_ii = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n) //check for unwanted integers
            return 0;

        else
        {
            sum_a += a[i]; // sum of 'elements' should be equal to sum of 'i' 
            sum_i += i;

            sum_aa += a[i] * a[i]; // multiplication sum of 'elements' should be equal to multiplication sum of 'i' 
            sum_ii += i * i;
        }
    }
    return (sum_aa == sum_ii && sum_a == sum_i);
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from working out the complexity yourself? Asking about that would be better so you can equip yourself to work that out for yourself going forward rather than just asking someone else to work it out for your every time. So do you have any thoughts on which is better?

Comment: [Fast O(N), speed O(N) size solution](https://pastebin.com/8TZ1Z5Vc)

Comment: @chmike, ah woops, huge difference. Deleted my earlier comment. Yours will do in its place :)

Comment: The second method fails because [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] has the same sum and sum of squares as [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7].

Comment: @eric postpischil you are right, very amazed you found that. i dont think our professor would have seen it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we need to fix `check_missing_a` because it's buggy. After the swap, `a[i]` might be out of bounds for following `a[a[i]]`. Fixed version:

```
int check_missing_a2(int *a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (i != a[i]) {
            if (a[i] < i || a[i] >= n || a[i] == a[a[i]])
                return 0;

            swap(&a[i], &a[a[i]]);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

We can even save a few comparisons as follows: (Thanks to @chmike)

```
int check_missing_a2(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n)
            return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (i != a[i]) {
            if (a[i] == a[a[i]])
                return 0;

            swap(&a[i], &a[a[i]]);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

---

**Complexity of `check_missing_a2`**

At first glance, one might think that `check_missing_a2` is slower than O(N) because the outer loop does N passes and there's another inner loop.

However, the inner loop performs at most N-1 swaps. For example, the following illustrates the number of swaps for each arrangement of the numbers in 0..N-1 for N=8:

```
# swaps   # arrangements
-------   --------------
      0                1
      1               28
      2              322
      3             1960
      4             6769
      5            13132
      6            13068
      7             5040
```

As @4386427  explained, every swap places at least one element in its correct position. Consequently there can't be more than N swaps.

This means that no part of the function is executed more than 2*N times, for a resulting complexity of O(N).

---

**Complexity of `check_missing_b`**

A single loop with N passes, for a complexity of O(N).

---

As for actual performance, I suspect that `check_missing_a2` will always be faster than `check_missing_b`.

Of course, there's also the issue that `check_missing_a2` changes the array and that `check_missing_b` could overflow.

Comment: This is correct but there is a bug left. You only checked if values 0 to i are bigger than 0 and smaller than n. But you swap `a[i]` and `a[a[i]]`. The problem is that the value `a[a[i]]` may be out of range. On the next iteration of the while loop the value `a[i]` will be out of range and `a[a[i]]` will be outside the array.

Comment: You provide two functions with the same name. The first one contains the bug. The second one, does the two pass and avoids the out of bound problem.

Comment: This is correct for the first iteration of the while loop, but not the next ones.

Comment: oops, I missed that you do it in the while loop. Then it is correct.

Comment: thank you you helped me understand complexity theory better, and fix those bugs

Answer (score 1):

Function `check_missing_b` is definitely O(n) because it has only one loop. It also has the property to not modify the input array `a`. However, it has a limitation in the magnitude of `n` because `sum_ii` might overflow.

Function `check_missing_a` has two loops and is less obvious to analyze. It also sort the values in the array `a` and thus modify the input array. This might be a problem. On the other hand it is not subject to overflow which is an advantage over the other function.

This function is a radix sort because each swap puts a value in its final place. There will be less than `n` swaps. This function is thus O(n).

Unfortunately, this function has also a problem. A value `a[a[i]]` may be bigger than `n` when `a[i] > i`. The function requires thus two pass on the elements. A first pass, ensures that no value is smaller than 0 and bigger than n-1. A second pass does the radix sort.

Here is my suggested implementation of the function `check_missing_a`.

```c
int check_missing_c(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n)
            return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        while (i != a[i]) {
            if (a[i] == a[a[i]])
                return 0;
            int tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[tmp];
            a[tmp] = tmp;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "A value a[a[i]] may be bigger than n"
technically i can add another argument  to my if statement.
 if (a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n)     ---->     if (a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n || (a[a[i]] < 0 || a[a[i]] >= n)

isn't that correct?

Comment: @Tiran It isn’t sufficient because it is in the while loop that the out of bound occurs. With your test that you do before the while loop, you will secure the second iteration of the while loop, but not further ones.